# How do I prevent ubuntu from installing on the usb?

Tags: system-installation, usb, 22.04

I'm trying linux for the first time so I'm new to all this. I would like some help in a way a six year old can understand.

**The problem:**
When I try to install ubuntu it installs the operating system on the USB stick I used to boot the PC, which makes the install very slow. When the operating system is installed the applications take forever to open (for example: settings takes 2-5 minutes to open). I would like to know how I can make sure that the operating system installs on the PC's storage and not the USB stick.

**Extra info:**

- I chose the minimal installation.
- I used the "erase disk and install ubuntu" option.
- When I try the "install ubuntu alongside windows" option it only show
  the option to choose the USB stick.
- I have a hp laptop which has windows 10 but came with windows 8.
- I'm installing ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64
- I used rufus 3.18 to create the boot usb

Comment: "When I try the "install ubuntu alongside windows" option it only show the option to choose the USB stick." This happens probably because you have no free space. Windows has all the space currently.
When using the "erase disk and install ubuntu" option where there any other indicators that it would install on the usb? Something that you might be able to switch.

Comment: The option to select which disk to install Ubuntu on is hidden in a dropdown menu in the top right corner.

Comment: @karel the dropdown menu I found in the top right corner contains the following options: 2 slide bars(sound and brightness), wired connected, wifi not connected, bluetooth on, fully charged, balanced, power off/log out. Is this the correct dropdown menu? If so, where can I find the disk settings?

Comment: The dropdown menu that I referred to already has a disk selected by default, but you can select a different disk on which to install Ubuntu from this dropdown menu.

Comment: @Natan after pressing Install now with the erase disk option it gives a popup. with somethins about partitions: "If you  continue, the changes listed below will be written on the disks. Otherwise you will be able to make further changes manually. WARNING: this will destroy all data on any partitions you have removed as well as on the partitions that are  going to be formatted. The partition tables of the following devices are changed: SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sdb) The following partitions are goingto be formated: Partition #1 of SCS1 (0,0,0) (sdb) as ESP Partition #2 of SCS1 (0,0,0) (sdb) as ext4"